# Angular ViewChild with Directive as selector returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a test component which contains an example of two directives (one as an attribute directive). In the test component I'm useing the ViewChild decorator to try and get a reference to the directives in the `ngAfterViewInit` handler. However the `ViewChild` for each directive I'm testing returns `undefined`. When I inspect the page though the directives are present in the DOM.

Here is a StackBlitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-f3g4sv?file=src%2Ftest.component.ts

Here is the test component:

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  QueryList,
  ViewChild,
  ViewChildren,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestContainerDirective } from './test-container.directive';
import { OtherContainerDirective } from './other-test-container.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, OtherContainerDirective],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrl: './test.component.scss',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppTestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(TestContainerDirective)
  public _testContainerRef!: TestContainerDirective;

  @ViewChild(OtherContainerDirective)
  public _otherContainerRef!: OtherContainerDirective;

  @ViewChildren(TestContainerDirective)
  _testContainerChildren!: QueryList<TestContainerDirective>;

  constructor() {}

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('_testContainerRef', this._testContainerRef);
    console.log('_otherContainerRef', this._testContainerRef);

    console.log('_testContainerChildren', this._testContainerChildren);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('_testContainerRef', this._testContainerRef);
      console.log('_otherContainerRef', this._testContainerRef);
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Here is its template:

```
<p>This is the test component</p>
<span>
  Open the console and look for the references to the directives below
</span>

<p></p>

<div appTestContainer>test container</div>

<other-container>other container</other-container>
```

And Here are the test directives:

```
@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[appTestContainer]',
})
export class TestContainerDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}
}

@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'other-container',
})
export class OtherContainerDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

This seems to be just like the approach in the docs so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing importing the `TestContainerDirective` in the `TestComponent`.

```
@Component({
  ...
  imports: [CommonModule, TestContainerDirective, OtherContainerDirective],
  ...
})
```

Also, there are some mistakes that you are referring "_otherContainerRef" as `this._testContainerRef`, supposing you mean `this._otherContainerRef`.

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.log('_testContainerRef', this._testContainerRef);
  console.log('_otherContainerRef', this._otherContainerRef);

  console.log('_testContainerChildren', this._testContainerChildren);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('_testContainerRef', this._testContainerRef);
    console.log('_otherContainerRef', this._otherContainerRef);
  }, 0);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jxhbts?file=src%2Ftest.component.ts)

Comment: Great catch! I'm a bit confused why there was no template error though if the `TestComponent` couldn't find the `TestContainerDirective` that would have given a clue that the import was missing.